# MySQL Import - ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line XY: Unknown column 'X' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql, import

I just received a dump from a co-worker and tried to import it to a new database which I just created (property-rights-new):

```
mysql -u root -p property-rights-new < pso_legacy.sql
```

I got the error **ERROR 1054 (42S22) at line XY: Unknown column 'article_id' in 'field list'**

```
REPLACE INTO `article` (`article_id`, `basearticle_id`, `project_id`, `user_id`, `category`, `product_description`, `article_nr`, `color`, `carton_qty`, `qty`, `carton`, `size`, `price`, `price_calculation_file`, `closed`, `dbinsert`, `$
        (1, NULL, '10001', 26, 'spare part bag window backside brush', _binary '', '1090', 'according', 50, 5000, 100, 'no', NULL, NULL, 1, '2010-11-11 09:14:21', '2011-08-01 16:08:46', NULL, NULL),
 ...
```

What is causing it?

NOTE: This is a [share your knowledge Q&A](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The error was caused by these two lines in the dump, which were placed somewhere at the very top:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `pso` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 */;
USE `pso`;
```

I had to delete them to make it work.

The cause is, that it creates and use's the database `pso` while I tried to import to the database `property-rights-new`